Designing and Registering a Command in FIWARE NGSI-LD for Data Download from a URL
I am working with FIWARE, specifically with NGSI-LD. My objective is to create an actuator to which I can send a command to download information from a URL.
To achieve this, I want to design the command and register it in the IoT Agent.
The command will receive the following parameters:

URL: the URL from which the file should be downloaded.
View: a parameter to add to the URL to specify the download format.
File: a parameter in the URL indicating the file we want to download.
Method: the method to use for downloading, in this case, "GET".

POST: http://localhost:4041/ngsi-ld/v1/commands

Headers:
    Content-Type: application/json

Body:
{
"download_json_data": [
  {
   "name": "download_json_data",
   "description": "Download JSON data from a URL.",
   "type": "command",
   "params": {
    "url": {
     "type": "string",
     "description": "URL from where data is downloaded."
    },
    "vista": {
     "type": "string",
     "description": "View parameter to specify download format."
    },
    "archivo": {
     "type": "string",
     "description": "Specifies the file to download."
    },
    "method": {
     "type": "string",
     "description": "Method used for download -> GET"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}

When I send this POST request, I get the following error:
Cannot POST /ngsi-ld/v1/command
What is the correct endpoint to register the command?

UPDATE
IoT Agent logs:
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.853Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Request for path [/iot/devices] query [{}] from [localhost:4041] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.854Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Body:

{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "bell001",
            "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
            "entity_type": "Bell",
            "apikey": "1234",
            "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltriLight",
            "transport": "HTTP",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "name": "ring",
                    "type": "command"
                }
            ],
            "static_attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "refStore",
                    "type": "Relationship",
                    "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

 | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.854Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceProvisioning | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Handling device provisioning request. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentJSON.Agent | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=deviceProvisioningHandler for device {"id":"bell001","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","staticAttributes":[{"name":"refStore","type":"Relationship","value":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}],"commands":[{"name":"ring","type":"command"}],"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltriLight","transport":"HTTP","internalId":null} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Looking for bindings for the function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Creating execution for function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Binding found for function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Binding found for function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Binding found for function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Binding found for function deviceProvisioningHandler and protocol null | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IOTAJSON.HTTP.Binding | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=httpbinding.deviceProvisioningHandler device {"id":"bell001","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","staticAttributes":[{"name":"refStore","type":"Relationship","value":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}],"commands":[{"name":"ring","type":"command"}],"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltriLight","transport":"HTTP","internalId":null} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.855Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for group params ["resource","apikey"] with queryObj {"resource":"/iot/json","apikey":"1234"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.857Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Device group for fields [["resource","apikey"]] not found: [{"resource":"/iot/json","apikey":"1234"}] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.858Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IOTAJSON.HTTP.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=httpbinding.deviceProvisioningHandler group {} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.858Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IOTAJSON.HTTP.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=httpbinding.setPollingAndDefaultTransport device {"id":"bell001","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","staticAttributes":[{"name":"refStore","type":"Relationship","value":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}],"commands":[{"name":"ring","type":"command"}],"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltriLight","transport":"HTTP","internalId":null} group {} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.858Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Looking for device with id [bell001] and queryParams [{"id":"bell001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","apikey":"1234"}]. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.867Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Device [bell001] not found. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.867Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for group params ["service","subservice","type","apikey"] with queryObj {"service":"openiot","subservice":"/","type":"Bell","apikey":"1234"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.870Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Device group data found: {"_id":"672b34818cb8fe2a5ab69cb2","resource":"","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","service":"openiot","subservice":"/"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.870Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Prepare device data:
{
    "id": "bell001",
    "apikey": "1234",
    "type": "Bell",
    "name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
    "service": "openiot",
    "subservice": "/",
    "staticAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "refStore",
            "type": "Relationship",
            "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"
        }
    ],
    "commands": [
        {
            "name": "ring",
            "type": "command"
        }
    ],
    "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltriLight",
    "transport": "HTTP",
    "internalId": null,
    "polling": true
} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=deviceData before merge with conf: {"id":"bell001","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","staticAttributes":[{"name":"refStore","type":"Relationship","value":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}],"commands":[{"name":"ring","type":"command"}],"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltriLight","transport":"HTTP","internalId":null,"explicitAttrs":true,"polling":true} defaults: [null,null,[],[],[],[],[]] fields: ["lazy","active","staticAttributes","commands","subscriptions"] configuration {"_id":"672b34818cb8fe2a5ab69cb2","resource":"","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","service":"openiot","subservice":"/"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=deviceData after merge with conf: {"id":"bell001","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001","service":"openiot","subservice":"/","active":null,"staticAttributes":[{"name":"refStore","type":"Relationship","value":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}],"lazy":null,"commands":[{"name":"ring","type":"command","object_id":"ring"}],"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltriLight","transport":"HTTP","internalId":null,"explicitAttrs":true,"polling":true,"subscriptions":[]} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Registering device into NGSI Service:
{
    "id": "bell001",
    "apikey": "1234",
    "type": "Bell",
    "name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
    "service": "openiot",
    "subservice": "/",
    "active": null,
    "staticAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "refStore",
            "type": "Relationship",
            "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"
        }
    ],
    "lazy": null,
    "commands": [
        {
            "name": "ring",
            "type": "command",
            "object_id": "ring"
        }
    ],
    "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltriLight",
    "transport": "HTTP",
    "internalId": null,
    "explicitAttrs": true,
    "polling": true,
    "subscriptions": []
} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Registration | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Sending LD device registrations to Context Broker at [http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations/] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Registration | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Using the following request:

{
    "url": "http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations/",
    "method": "POST",
    "json": {
        "type": "ContextSourceRegistration",
        "information": [
            {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "type": "Bell",
                        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001"
                    }
                ],
                "propertyNames": [
                    "ring"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "mode": "exclusive",
        "operations": [
            "updateOps"
        ],
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:4041",
        "contextSourceInfo": [
            {
                "key": "jsonldContext",
                "value": [
                    "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld",
                    "http://context/json-context.jsonld"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "@context": [
            "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld",
            "http://context/json-context.jsonld"
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "fiware-service": "openiot",
        "fiware-servicepath": "/",
        "NGSILD-Tenant": "openiot",
        "NGSILD-Path": "/",
        "Content-Type": "application/ld+json"
    }
}

 | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.RestUtils | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=executeWithSecurity | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.871Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for group params ["type"] with queryObj {"type":"Bell"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.873Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Device group data found: {"_id":"672b34818cb8fe2a5ab69cb2","resource":"","apikey":"1234","type":"Bell","service":"openiot","subservice":"/"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.874Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Request | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Options: {
    "url": "http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/csourceRegistrations/",
    "method": "POST",
    "json": {
        "type": "ContextSourceRegistration",
        "information": [
            {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "type": "Bell",
                        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001"
                    }
                ],
                "propertyNames": [
                    "ring"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "mode": "exclusive",
        "operations": [
            "updateOps"
        ],
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:4041",
        "contextSourceInfo": [
            {
                "key": "jsonldContext",
                "value": [
                    "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld",
                    "http://context/json-context.jsonld"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "@context": [
            "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld",
            "http://context/json-context.jsonld"
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "fiware-service": "openiot",
        "fiware-servicepath": "/",
        "NGSILD-Tenant": "openiot",
        "NGSILD-Path": "/",
        "Content-Type": "application/ld+json"
    }
} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Request | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Response {
    "type": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/errors/BadRequestData",
    "title": "Non-String item in Registration::contextSourceInfo[X]",
    "detail": "value"
} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.886Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Registration | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Registration error connecting to the Context Broker: 400 | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceProvisioning | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Device provisioning failed due to the following error:  | comp=IoTAgent Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 400
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.886Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | trans=ef05282a-0e92-425e-9203-54c020265f5b | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | from=n/a | srv=openiot | subsrv=/ | msg=Error [BAD_REQUEST] handling request: Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 400 | comp=IoTAgent
time=2024-11-06T09:25:30.887Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | trans=b280b358-2376-4df2-b402-6cbf6d7b8000 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=response-time: 34 | comp=IoTAgent


You do not provision devices directly into a context broker. You need to provision devices and service groups into an IoT Agent instead.
For example, to say all measures with an apiKey=1234 -
curl -iX POST \
  'http://<iot-agent>/iot/services' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "1234",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Bell",
     "resource":    ""
   }
 ]
}'

and then provision the device into the IoT Agent like this:
curl -iX POST \
  'http://<iot-agent>/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "bell001",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
      "entity_type": "Bell",
      "apikey":      "1234",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "MQTT",
      "commands": [
        { "name": "ring", "type": "Property" }
       ],
       "static_attributes": [
         {"name":"refStore", "type": "Relationship","value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'

Assuming you are using IoT Agent for JSON, then the command sent to the context broker would be:
curl -L -X PATCH 'http://<context-broker>/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Device:bell001/attrs/ring' \
    -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{

        "type": "Property",
        "value": { ... your JSON goes here }

}'

In other words patching the attribute which corresponds to the command. The JSON is then passed on to MQTT or HTTP depending upon how the device was provisioned.

I don't think this really answers my question... Could you be more specific on how I should register the command I want to use in the IoT Agent?

Not sure what you mean here. The question asked "What is the correct endpoint to register the command?" - When registering the command you use /service and /groups endpoints. You can see a full working example here
Do you mean what is the payload into the context broker?

I've tried what you answered and I'm getting a "BAD REQUEST" type message. What i need is to be able to send a command that makes an actuator connect to an URL and download the data I ask for through the command

Which endpoint? Context broker or IoT Agent and what does the error message state? The error message should give more information as to what is going wrong.

This is what the error says: "Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 400"

And what is your URL?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
